# Line-Weekly Report

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I'm doing a line-weekly report where the user will select two dates for this report. For example, the user wants to see the data between two dates. I'm doing it in a web application.

I have written code like this:

```
@"select distinct d1.machine as Machine,CASE  WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 7:00:00.000' 

AND '1900-01-01 14:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift1'   WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 

15:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 22:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift2' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 

23:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 23:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift3' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 

00:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 06:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift3' END as Shiftname,CASE  WHEN 

t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 7:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 14:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator1' 

  WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 15:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 22:59:59.999' 

THEN 'Operator2' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 23:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 

23:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator3' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-

01 06:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator3' END as OperatorName, Date=convert(varchar

(12),t.date,101),Time=convert(varchar(8),t.time,8),Temprature as 

Temperature,Pressure,Co2,Do2,pH,Speed,Flow from datalogging1 d1 inner join   temprature3 

t  on d1.date=t.date inner join pressure3 p on p.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)

=datepart(hour,p.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,p.time) inner join co23 

c on c.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,c.time) and datepart

(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,c.time) inner join do23 d on d.date=t.date and datepart

(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,d.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,d.time) 

inner join ph3 h on h.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,h.time) and 

datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,h.time) inner join speed3 s on s.date=t.date and 

datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,s.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart

(minute,s.time) inner join flow3 f on f.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart

(hour,f.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,f.time) where t.date 

between '"+txtfromdate+@"' and '"+txttodate+@"' and  line='"+ddlline.SelectedItem+@"' union 

select distinct d1.machine as Machine, CASE  WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 7:00:00.000'

 AND '1900-01-01 14:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift1'   WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 

15:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 22:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift2' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01

 23:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 23:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift3' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01

 00:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 6:59:59.999' THEN 'Shift3' END as Shiftname,CASE  WHEN 

t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 7:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 14:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator1'   

WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 15:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 22:59:59.999' 

THEN 'Operator2' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 23:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 

23:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator3' WHEN t.time BETWEEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-

01 6:59:59.999' THEN 'Operator3' END as OperatorName,Date=convert(varchar

(12),t.date,101),Time=convert(varchar(8),t.time,8),Temprature as 

Temperature,Pressure,Co2,Do2,pH,Speed,Flow from datalogging1 d1 inner join temprature3 t 

on d1.date=t.date inner join pressure3 p on p.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)

=datepart(hour,p.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,p.time) inner join co23

 c on c.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,c.time) and datepart

(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,c.time) inner join do23 d on d.date=t.date and datepart

(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,d.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,d.time) 

inner join ph3 h on h.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,h.time) and 

datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,h.time) inner join speed3 s on s.date=t.date and 

datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart(hour,s.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart

(minute,s.time) inner join flow3 f on f.date=t.date and datepart(hour,t.time)=datepart

(hour,f.time) and datepart(minute,t.time)=datepart(minute,f.time) where t.date=dateadd

(day,1,'"+txttodate+@"') and line='"+ddlline.SelectedItem+@"' order by 

date,time,machine,shiftname,operatorname"
```

It's executing in SQL Server, but when I'm including it in my application it's showing an error like

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using string concatenation for `txtfromdate` and `txttodate` try passing them as parameters after you've converted to `DateTime`, or `SqlDateTime`. Your problem is almost certainly in how the text in those controls is being formatted that SQL Server can't interpret.